# Testing React form submit with jest not working

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test 'mock' function execution & following error occurs:

```
Expected number of calls: >= 1                                                                                                                                                                                 
Received number of calls:    0
```

That points to .toHaveBeenCalled() function.

**CreateTodo Test**

```
import {CreateTodo} from "./CreateTodo";
import {screen, render, fireEvent} from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";

test('adding item test', async () => {
    const mock = jest.fn();
    render(<CreateTodo onAdd={mock}/>);

    const input = screen.getByRole('textbox');

    userEvent.type(input, 'hello{enter}');

    expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

However when I'm adding

```
fireEvent.submit(input);
```

After userEvent.type... test works perfectly.

How do I pass props, submit & etc?

**Flow**

- onAdd prop is function that is placed inside CreateTodo parent component
- onSubmit form new todo is being added to array Todos by lifting up state to a CreateTodo parent

So, CreateTodo component lifts-up state to a parent, then parent mutates Todos & re-renders.

Maybe it can be related, that onAdd function is being called in parent component, not in CreateTodo?

**CreateTodo Component**

```
import {useState} from "react";

export const CreateTodo = ({onAdd}) => {
    const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
        text: '',
        completed: false,
        id: new Date().valueOf()
    });

    const {text, completed} = inputs;

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!text) return;

        onAdd(inputs);
    }

    const handleChange = ({target: {name, value, checked}}) => {
        setInputs(prev => {
            return {
                ...prev,
                [name]: name === "completed" ? checked : value,
            }
        });
    }

    return <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type="checkbox" checked={completed} name="completed" onChange={handleChange}/>
        <input type="text" name="text" value={text} onChange={handleChange}/>
    </form>
}
```

Edit: If you are downvoting, then write a reason please, thanks!
(ReactJS tag only for highlighted syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `async/await` for `userEvent.type()` method.

You need to add a submit button inside the `form` element if there are more than one form controls(two inputs element in your case) so that we can submit the form by keypress <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. If you don't want the button displayed in the UI, add the `hidden` attribute.

See [implicit-submission](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#implicit-submission)

> If the form has no submit button, then the implicit submission mechanism must do nothing if the form has more than one field that blocks implicit submission, and must submit the form element from the form element itself otherwise.

E.g.

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <input type='checkbox' checked={completed} name='completed' onChange={handleChange} />
    <input type='text' name='text' value={text} onChange={handleChange} />
    <input type='submit' hidden />
</form>
```

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import React from 'react';
import { CreateTodo } from './CreateTodo';

test('adding item test', async () => {
    const mock = jest.fn();
    render(<CreateTodo onAdd={mock} />);
    const input = screen.getByRole('textbox');
    await userEvent.type(input, 'hello{enter}');
    expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

package versions:

```json
"@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
"react": "^16.14.0",
```